# Socket.IO + Node.js + SSL

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ssl

I would like to run simply chat using Node.js (0.5.11) and Socket.IO. I've working it with pure HTTP but i need to start SSL.
I've generate key and certificate like in the wiki: http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_ssl

The code i use:

**app.js:**

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
};

var server = tls.createServer(options, function(cleartextStream) {
  console.log('server connected',
              cleartextStream.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  cleartextStream.write("welcome!\n");
  cleartextStream.setEncoding('utf8');
  cleartextStream.pipe(cleartextStream);
});
server.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

The server starts good. Problem begins when i want to refer to socket.io on index.php:

```
<script src="https://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Firebug gives me status Aborted and i cannot work with "io" object becouse it is not loaded. I've also try "http://local..." in the src attribute but with no change.
What am i doing wrong?
Could someone give me an advice or good tutorial how to run Socket.IO wth SSL?

Thanks already for reply

Comment: A tls.createServer is not the same as a https.createServer.  Which one do you actually need?

Comment: I need https becouse i need to send encrypted data in the chat.

Comment: Have you tried using the https.createServer instead of tls.CreateServer?

Comment: Changing the name from "tls" to "https" wouldn't change anything and trying to require('https') dont work

Comment: It should work: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.10/api/https.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```

You just need this as it will autodiscover, just in case you forget to update port and address if connecting to another address.

Where is socketio included in your server?
that seems to be the problem

```
var sockio = require("socket.io");
var io = sockio.listen(server);
```

Comment: How it could autodiscover if "client-side" have no SocketIO installed. It need to be downloaded from server. I need to check your code but i cannot do it now, tomorow i'll reply. Thanks!

Comment: the socketio js file you use on client side is sent by node server automatically, just search here on stackoverflow, that question is seen around a lot. And check this http://socket.io/#how-to-use in Sending and getting data (acknowledgements).